# Running Tails from USB without rebooting

Tags: tails

I'm installing Tails on my USB drive and its working as expected. However, when I plug the USB on my colleague's PC, it's not recognizing. There's no firewall or any security limitation.

I would like to know how to make Tails completely portable. If installed and used via Kali Linux, I would have to reboot the PC, which I don't want to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can not boot into OS inside a USB while you are in an OS (unless you run it inside a Virtual Machine, not USB). You have to reboot and if required select the USB, to boot into Tails. May be your friends computer doesn't allow boot from USB (or you did not select the option while booting).

Comment: OK so if I'm using a VM, then can you please tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Install tails inside a VM: https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/virtualbox/index.en.html

Comment: Do you want tails to be working on another PC or do you want a solution which doesn't require reboot?

Comment: I would want to work with tails on another PC without rebooting.

Comment: Dont'run Tails inside VirtualBOX or VMWare, use instead Whonix